# A proof involving the relationship between injection, prime numbers, and the gcd.

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a$ and $m$ be integers with $0 < a < m$.  Let $f:\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ 
 be the function defined by $f(\overline{x}) = \overline{a}\cdot \overline{x}$.  Prove that $f$ is injective if and only if $\gcd(a,m) = 1$.

So far, I have two different approaches to this problem, but they don’t get me anywhere.The first way is to assume that f is invective, which means that $f(\overline{x}) =f(\overline{y})$, and thus we have that $\overline{x}=\overline{y}$.  Therefore, from this we can say that $x\sim y$, which means that $ x-y \in m\mathbb{Z}$.Hence, m divides $x-y$.  Thus, $x-y=km$ for some integer k.  After that, I separated this into two possible cases:  One in which m is composite, and one in which it is prime. After that, I got stuck. The  other  approach  I  had  in  mind  was  a  proof  by  contradiction,  where  I  assume  that $gcd(a, m)>1$.  But I didn't know where to go after that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the order of $\bar a$ is less than $m$, then clearly the morphism is not injective. If the order is $m$, then the morphism is injective. Try showing that $\bar a<m$ is equivalent to $\gcd(a,m)\neq1$.